# Transduction coefficient of an electromechanical system

Tags: acoustics, dimensional-analysis, units, resonance

I have been recently doing a physics experiment which requires me to determine the transduction coefficient of a speaker system, undergoing electromechanical resonance, in an AC circuit. The quantity T, has units of (Ωs/kg)^0.5. I did some dimensional analysis on this to help identify what T actually means.

[T] = [L][I][T]^-1, and the overall units are Amp meters/second, or Am/s. I'm trying to interpret what T represents from these units, so any help with that would be great. If you could tell me about any other quantities with similar/the same units, I would also really appreciate it. At a vague guess, I'm assuming this coefficient represents in some way how much of the electrical signal of the system is changed into a mechanical signal for the speaker to make sound.

Comment: When you start with $[T]=\sqrt{\Omega\text{s/kg}}$ and use $\Omega=\text{V/A}=\text{Vs/C}$ and 
$$
\text{V}=\frac{\text{kg m}^2}{\text{C s}^2}
$$
you should end up with 
$$
\frac{\Omega\,\text{s}}{\text{kg}}=\frac{\text{m}^2}{\text{C}^2\text{s}}
$$
To me this looks strange. The square root of this is clearly not $\text{Am/s}.$
You may want to post this on [ESE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).